# Orient textbox or text in textbox to vertical with XlsxWriter?

Tags: python, xlsxwriter

I can't find example how to set the vertical orientation of a text in text box

I find how to rotate text in cell, but I need rotate text in text box

**text box code**

```
text = 'Some text in a textbox'
options = {
'font': {'color': 'white'},
'align': {'vertical': 'middle',
           'horizontal': 'center',
          },
'gradient': {'colors': ['red', 'blue']},
}
worksheet.insert_textbox(row, col, text, options)
```

**code with rotation text in cell**

```
cell_format = workbook.add_format()
cell_format.set_rotation(90)
worksheet.write(1, 1, 'This text is rotated')
worksheet.set_column(col, col, None, cell_format)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That isn't a currently available feature but if you open a [Feature Request on GitHub](https://github.com/jmcnamara/XlsxWriter/issues) I can add it.

**Update**: This is now available in XlsxWriter >= 1.2.4.

From the updated [docs](https://xlsxwriter.readthedocs.io/working_with_textboxes.html#textbox-formatting-text-rotation):

> The text_rotation option can be used to set the text rotation for the entire textbox:

```py
    worksheet.insert_textbox('B2', 'Text rotated up',
                             {'text_rotation': 90})
```

[image]